# Easily override NuGet DLL in development (VS 2015)

Tags: dll, msbuild, nuget, visual-studio-2015, nuget-package

We have 3 solutions in VS 2015 containing C# projects. One of those creates a NuGet package and the other 2 reference a DLL from that NuGet package. (The DLL contains the interface between two parts of an application.) A TeamCity build server builds the DLL and the NuGet package, automatically setting its version.

In development I want to be able to easily test changes to the DLL without committing them and waiting for the package to be built. What's the best way to do this? Ideally I want to say: *if `C:\Build\My.dll` exists then use it regardless of its version, otherwise use `version 1.2.3.4` of the `MyDLL NuGet package`*. Is there any way to specify that and have it "survive" NuGet upgrades?

I tried temporarily deleting the reference to that DLL and adding a reference directly to the version I want, but the problem is that it's referenced in many projects and doing this for all of them is quite a hassle.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it can be done in the BeforeBuild step by removing the existing NuGet reference. This way, the NuGet reference item itself is unchanged and can be freely replaced by NuGet during upgrades, but during the build my version of the DLL gets used (if it exists).

It also takes a slight hack to remove the reference regardless of version.

```
  <Target Name="BeforeBuild">
    <!-- Override NuGet package with a local copy in dev, if available -->
    <PropertyGroup>
        <ReplacementLocalDllPath>Some\Path\My.dll</ReplacementLocalDllPath>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <ItemGroup Condition="Exists($(ReplacementLocalDllPath))">
      <!-- Remove any version of the DLL to be replaced -->
      <ReferenceToBeRemoved Include="@(Reference)" Condition="$([System.String]::Copy(&quot;%(Reference.Filename)&quot;).StartsWith('My'))" />
      <Reference Remove="@(ReferenceToBeRemoved)" />
      <!-- Add the local DLL, ignoring its version -->
      <Reference Include="My, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
        <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
        <HintPath>$(ReplacementLocalDllPath)</HintPath>
      </Reference>
    </ItemGroup>
  </Target>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use conditional references in your csproj file at achieve this. Check out this MSDN link for more info: [MSBuild Conditional Constructs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164307.aspx)

Comment: I tried that and it works great as long as you don't upgrade the NuGet package. When you upgrade it, however, it removes the condition reference and adds an unconditional one.

Comment: I tried adding a conditional reference to a test project. It survived a NuGet package update. I had this ItemGroup after the initial dll reference. `<ItemGroup Condition="Exists('C:\Temp\ConditionalProjRefTest\log4net.dll')">
    <Reference Include="log4net">
      <HintPath>C:\Temp\ConditionalProjRefTest\log4net.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
  </ItemGroup>`

Comment: Yes, but did you also have the NuGet reference? That needs to be conditional (Condition="!Exists(...)"), too, otherwise there is a duplicate.

Comment: Yes. I do have the NuGet reference as well. Here is the relevant section: `<ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="log4net, Version=1.2.13.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=669e0ddf0bb1aa2a, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\log4net.2.0.3\lib\net40-full\log4net.dll</HintPath>
      <Private>True</Private>
    </Reference>
    </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup Condition="Exists('C:\Temp\ConditionalProjRefTest\log4net.dll')">
    <Reference Include="log4net">
      <HintPath>C:\Temp\ConditionalProjRefTest\log4net.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
  </ItemGroup>`

Comment: To add to the previous comment, I initially had a refernce to log4net package 2.0.0 and updated it to log4net 2.0.3

Comment: @EM you might want to try the ReferencePath approach. The order in which Visual Studio looks for references is described here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/manishagarwal/archive/2005/09/28/474769.aspx . Based on that, having the ReferencePath set will override any HintPath specified and allow you to have dev versions of dlls without having to modify your project file.

Comment: So when the file in ConditionalProjRefTest exists don't you get an error about a duplicate assembly reference, since it tries to reference both that and the NuGet file?

`ReferencePath` is an interesting possibility, but I'd still need to manage 2 Reference Items somehow, because the NuGet one is liable to be overwritten during an upgrade.

Anyway, I think I figured out a way that works. Posting my answer...