# Remove MSBuild DLL reference regardless of version (by wildcard) in VS 2015

Tags: c#, msbuild, visual-studio-2015, msbuild-4.0

In a C# project I have a DLL reference that I want to remove before the build (to be replaced with another - this an attempted solution to [Easily override NuGet DLL in development (VS 2015)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33353941/easily-override-nuget-dll-in-development-vs-2015)). The following target seems to work:

```
  <Target Name="BeforeBuild">
    <ItemGroup Condition="Exists('..\..\..\Build\My.dll')">
      <Reference Remove="My, Version=1.2.3.4, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL" />
      <Reference Include="My, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
        <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
        <HintPath>..\..\..\Build\My.dll</HintPath>
      </Reference>
    </ItemGroup>
  </Target>
```

The problem with this is that I need to specify the exact version of the DLL to remove, which can change. I want to remove it regardless of version. I tried a wildcard

```
      <Reference Remove="My, Version=*, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL" />
```

... but that didn't seem to match anything, because I got `error CS1704: An assembly with the same simple name 'My' has already been imported.`

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <ReferenceToBeRemoved Include="@(Reference)" Condition="$([System.String]::Copy(&quot;%(Reference.Filename)&quot;).StartsWith('MyDllName'))" />
  <Reference Remove="@(ReferenceToBeRemoved)" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Answer (score -1):

use:

```
<Reference Remove="My, Version=1.2.3.4, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL" >
    <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
</ Reference>
```

Comment: Nice idea, but no, it doesn't work: `<SpecificVersion> is not valid. Child elements are not allowed below a item remove element.`