# How to Remove node from csproj file in BeforeBuild Task?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, msbuild, msbuild-task

One of my 3rd party libraries has a license file that it always adds to the csproj file each time we load the designer in VS. If I simply ignore the file, I still need to delete in VS from the Solution Explorer and I tend to forget before pushing to our source control as it is not needed. If there a way to remove the entry in the BeforeBuild target or similar if it is found?

Below is what I'm looking to remove on each build during a build:

```
<ItemGroup>
...
   <EmbeddedResource Include="Properties\licenses.licx" />
...
</ItemGroup>
```

this is a good start, but I could not figure out how to modify for my needs: [Remove MSBuild DLL reference regardless of version (by wildcard) in VS 2015](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33367161/remove-msbuild-dll-reference-regardless-of-version-by-wildcard-in-vs-2015)

Comment: Troopers's solution is good, if you want to remove it before build, you can refer to this code:  <IncludeResource>false</IncludeResource> <Target Name="BeforeBuild">
    <ItemGroup>
      <EmbeddedResource Remove="Resources\Resource1.resx" Condition="$(IncludeResource)==false"/>
    </ItemGroup>
  </Target>

Comment: @starain Don't forget to upvote good posts when you see them :)

Comment: @starain this seems to be closer to what I'm looking for, but it seems to not actually remove the file from the project.

Comment: What's the detail code of you project file? Is it included in the Compile item, like this:    <Compile Include="Resources\Resource1.Designer.cs">
      <AutoGen>True</AutoGen>
      <DesignTime>True</DesignTime>
      <DependentUpon>Resource1.resx</DependentUpon>
    </Compile> If so, you can remove it in BeforeBuild target too.   <Compile Remove="Resources\Resource1.Designer.cs" Condition="$(IncludeResource)==false"/>

Comment: What's the result now? Do you solve that issue?

Answer (score 1):

You could create a property setted on the configuration
and test the condition to include the file

Like this :

```
<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'Release'">
    <WithLicense>1</WithLicense>
</PropertyGroup>
<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'Debug'">
    <WithLicense>0</WithLicense>
</PropertyGroup>
<ItemGroup>
    ...
    <EmbeddedResource Include="Properties\licenses.licx" Condition="$(WithLicense)==1"/>
    ...
</ItemGroup>
```

Comment: This does not work in my case since each time I modify a designer form, this node is recreated and the condition is removed.

Comment: Try to set the `EmbeddedResource` node in a separated `ItemGroup` node with the condition on `ItemGroup` instead of `EmbeddedResource`